# C# - Passing variables in 'foreach' to other file

Tags: c#, forms, variables, public

In my project I have 2 files:

- `Form1.cs`
- `Form2.cs`

In `Form1.cs` I have the following code:

```
foreach (var file in files)
{

    File.Copy(file, tempPath + @"\" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file));
    if (File.Exists(file))
      {
         //here I want to use a custom MsgBox with a checkbox (form2)
      }
}
```

In `Form2.cs` I created a custom MsgBox, there I want to use the last filename (string file in files) in the displayed text.

It says "file" is not available. How can I share the variable between the 2 forms? I know that I have to declare it public but when I try so It messes up my code.

Comment: your files can have multiple records? & your label is single, totally confusing

Comment: I just want to use "string file" in my other file..

Comment: How many? Your foreach can return multiple?

Comment: Maybe I tell you a bit more about my idea. In foreach, files get copied. If a file already exists, a custom MessageBox pops up and in the MessageBox-text I want to use the name of the already existing file.

Comment: @loyd sorry I didn't get your point, is pop-up is your form 2

Comment: Yes. I had to create a custom one in order to have a checkbox in it.

Comment: Update your question with proper requirement & code what you tried than people might help you.

Comment: Your files are in project directory, The code will look for file in the output directory (Bin).

Answer (score 0):

Everything depends on context; there is no single common shared global context, except for `static` fields, and *please* don't abuse them for this. There is no single "my form1 / my form2" - you can have 0, 1 or many of each - and the code has no way of guessing what you intend.

The best thing to do is probably to make the *instance* of `Form2` (please rename it!) available to the `refresh()` method, so that you can do things like:

```
void Refresh(Form2 form)
{
   var files = <mydirectory>

   foreach (string file in files)
   {
      form.Text = file;
   }
}
```

however, this will mean that you only *actually* display the *last* `file` value. So; what do you want to do with the others that aren't the last? Are the multiple instances of the other form? *we don't know!*

Comment: Thanks for your time. I updated my question and hope you understand my intention.

Comment: @loyd I don't think that changes my answer... for the refresh method to have access to any particular form, either the refresh method must *create* the form, or the existing form needs to be *made available* to it...

Comment: Allright.. I try to read a bit more about it. As this question makes no sense for others you can delete it, I don't think it will help anyone else.. Thanks for your time :)